# Parse/PFNullability.h not found

Tags: swift, parse-platform, facebook-sdk-4.0

Hi I'm trying to update Facebook SDK from 3.x to 4.0 by using Parse.

It works if I don't use Facebook integration.
But when I try to use Facebook,PFFacebookUtils.h generate error.
That said "Parse/PFNullability.h not found" heppened.

ParseFacebookUtilsV4/PFFacebookUtils.h file try to import 3 files from Parse.framework.

```
#import <Parse/PFConstants.h>
#import <Parse/PFNullability.h>
#import <Parse/PFUser.h>
```

"PFConstants.h" and "PFUser.h" seems to be imported successfully.
So search path should be okay.

And I think "PFNullability.h" actually exist and I don't know why only "PFNullability.h" cause error.

Please help me!

Here's my bridge header file.

```
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <Bolts/Bolts.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import <ParseFacebookUtilsV4/PFFacebookUtils.h>
```

I'm using parse-library-1.7.1 on Xcode 6.3.1 (Swift).

Comment: definitely upgrade to 1.7.2 if you can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem.

Since I imported frameworks and deleted them again and again, I have multiple records in my "Framework Search Path", "Header Search Path", and "Library Search Path".

So I removed all frameworks and deleted all paths ( I mean make same as my new project ) and re-added frameworks again.

And it works.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

For Facebook SDK v4.0, you need PFFacebookUtilsV4, not the regular PFFacebookUtils. It should be available with the latest Parse release.

Comment: Thank you for responding me. But I imported PFFacebookUtilsV4 actually.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I had the same issue but it was because I wasn't using V4 for me...Your bridging header looks good, but are you sure FBSDKCoreKit is what you need to be importing for Facebook?

Comment: Actually this was my fault. I deleted all frameworks and paths and re-added frameworks again, and it works now. Once again thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Parse.h
bellow from

```
#import <Parse/PFUserAuthenticationDelegate.h>
```

Added

```
#import <Parse/PFNullability.h>
```

Comment: but when I made a clean on project .. had fault in the above import. So the problem was that need to clean the project.